# How to run Node.js app in web server and call it via public URL

Tags: node.js, webserver

I've been given a basic **Node.js** (which I don't have experience with) **app** that I need to run on a web server and make it publicly accessible via a URL. If it was a html/javascript web app with a index.html file, I could just place all its files in a folder of the server, point a domain there and voilà, all done.

Unfortunately, this Node.js app has an `index.js` file (no html), which of course does nothing when I access it via URL. There is a `views/index.ejs` file in the app's folder with some HTML that looks like would render the interface of this simple app.

I've already installed Node.js in the server and I can call it via CLI, so that part I got running, but I've been searching about how to run the app itself and I can't figure it out, I presume because I might be getting the whole concept of running Node.js apps wrong.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: Start with `node index.js` or `npm start`. app's will normally run it's own web server on some port, which is often defaulted to 3000

Comment: @Matt that would be a one-time CLI command and then point the browser to wherever the index.js is located and in that port?

Comment: Yep, so most dev environments will be accessed with: http://localhost:3000.  You can either have users access the app directly on a server, or put a reverse proxy (apache, nginx etc) from your web server to the app.